# Stout has acetaminophen (tylenol) aftertaste

Tags: off-flavor, stout, aftertaste

TL;DR : My beer has an acetaminophen aftertaste, what could this be ?

I brewed an espresso oatmeal Stout 4 months ago. It had a hard time carbonating and has an acrid/bitter (burnt? too much dark malt?) aftertaste. It mellowed a bit with time. To me, this aftertaste now resembles acetaminophen (without the coating, just the white stuff, which is pretty bitter).

Recipe : https://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/espresso-oatmeal-stout-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tasted acetaminophen, but the 130g of black malt is probably your culprit. I made a stout with a similar amount, and the resulting beer was acrid and unpleasant. Aging mellowed it a bit, but it never turned into what I'd call a pleasant beer.

For what it's worth, the only roasted malts I use in my stouts are roasted barley, and a small amount of chocolate. Black malt is no longer welcome in my brewery.

Comment: Thanks! I would have pointed one of the dark malts as the culprit if I have had to choose. I just had no idea which one. I'll take your advice for my next oatmeal stout!!